# Getting error "Enter a URL that contains the root domain." on apps.dev.microsoft.com

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

I'm developing an app using the Outlook Rest Api. Part of the process is registering the Redirect URI.

I kept on getting the error "Enter a URL that contains the root domain." when I add this URI

https://staging.connectapp.com/

With my other redirect URI everything is alright.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add all the relevant (and not more) code to your question, so others can have a look at it

Comment: Having the same issue. There is no code: go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, register an app, add platform Web, specify a redirect url that is NOT https://www.domain.com, but some CNAME address (mine looks like https://dev.domain.com) , and it gives this error and won't save.

Comment: Hi guys - this is a known restriction that we're looking into removing.  You have to have a single top-level domain at this time. So if you have https://connectapp.com, you should be able to register https://staging.connectapp.com just fine.  But you won't be able to register https://foo.com as well.

Comment: @dstrockis we have been able to register urls with 'localhost' but for mobile local testing we need a way to register hostname urls like 'http://example.dev:1234/authorize', is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not at the moment. We do allow using a default mobile URI that is listed in the portal if you add the mobile platform. Does that suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I added the root domain (in this case https://connectapp.com), I could then add multiple subdomains. If I just had two subdomains, I got the error as above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Adding https://domain.com/keep-this-url-because-one-drive-wont-work-with-two-subdomains-otherwise worked like a charm when I needed two subdomains. Thanks!